# A $C_3$ free graph, degrees inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, inequality

If $G$ is a $C_3$ free graph, for any edge $(x,y)$ of $G$ I need to prove that $$\deg(x)+\deg(y)<|V(G)|+1.$$Any hints/answers will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y)$ is an edge of $G$ and that $|V(G)|=n$ is the number of vertices of $G$. We know there can't be a $z\in V(G)$ (Where $V$ is the set of vertices of $G$), such that both $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$ are edges of $G$. Thus, any vertex $z\in V(G)-\{x,y\}$, is connected to $x$ (and not to $y$), connected to $y$ (and not to $x$) or connected to neither of them. Thus, for all $n-2$ vertices in $V-\{x,y\}$, we know it is connected to at most one of $x$ and $y$, so the number of connections of $x$ and $y$ together to points of $V-\{x,y\}$ is $n-2$. Together with the edge $(x,y)$, which is counted twice, we get a maximum number of connections (that is, $\deg(x)+\deg(y)$) of $n-2+2=n<n+1=|V(G)|+1$.

**EDIT**
Suppose we have
$$
...\equiv x-y\equiv...
$$
where $-$ is an edge and $\equiv$ are the other edges from $x$ and $y$. We know that the number of other edges is at most $n-2$. When calculating $\deg(x)+\deg(y)$, we have to calculate the total number of edges starting/ending in $x$ and $y$. We know that '$-$' starts in $x$ and ends in $y$ (or the other way around), so we have to count is as an edge in $\deg(x)$ and in $\deg(y)$, and therefore we have to add two to $n-2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this off a text book or your own proof?

Comment: This is just a proof I thought of myself, but I think I have seen it in a lecture once before.

Comment: can you explain me the part "Together with the edge $(x,y)$, which is counted twice" if possible which is in the 7th line of the proof

Comment: @Heisenberg, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $x$ and $y$ are connected to the same vertex then there is a triangle in the graph.